# how to iterate all the pdf files in a folder for data extraction using apache tika

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-tika

There are multiple PDF's in the PDF folder with different names.

```
 <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name="data"/>
        <dataSource type="URLDataSource" baseUrl="${solr.install.dir}/example/exampledocs/PDF" name="main"/>
```

How do i iterate through all these files and index each document content with the document name as the key.

Comment: Found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252822/indexing-all-documents-in-doc-folder-in-to-solr-filelistentityprocessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly this is demonstrated in [the refreshed DIH Tika example](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/branch_6_6/solr/example/example-DIH/solr/tika/conf/tika-data-config.xml) that will will ship with Solr 6.6.